# Android GraphView Custom Horizontal Label for Bar Graph

Tags: android, android-graphview

I try to use GraphView to create graph in my app

I try Bar graph with below code

```
@Override
public void initGraph(GraphView graph) {
    // first series is a line
    BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new BarGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {

            new DataPoint(5,5)
    });
    series.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    series.setSpacing(10);
    series.setAnimated(true);
    graph.addSeries(series);

    BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series1 = new BarGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(2,10)
    });
    series1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    series1.setSpacing(10);
    series1.setAnimated(true);
    graph.addSeries(series1);


    BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series2 = new BarGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(3,3)
    });
    series2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    series2.setSpacing(10);
    series2.setAnimated(true);
    graph.addSeries(series2);

    BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series3 = new BarGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, 5)
    });
    series3.setColor(Color.RED);
    series3.setSpacing(10);
    series3.setAnimated(true);
    graph.addSeries(series3);

    graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setMinX(0);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxX(5);

    StaticLabelsFormatter staticLabelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graph);
    // legend
    series.setTitle("SQA");
    series2.setTitle("IT");
    series1.setTitle("NOS");
    series3.setTitle("YOUTH");
    graph.getLegendRenderer().setVisible(true);
    graph.getLegendRenderer().setAlign(LegendRenderer.LegendAlign.TOP);
    staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(new String[] {"YOUTH", "NOS", "IT", "SQA"});
    graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(staticLabelsFormatter);
}
```

[image]
The result not as I expected as the labels that show up only 3....1 of them is not showing. 
Is there something I missing here? Any answer will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bar series plots your data points in increasing order by x value, 
so

- series3(0,5) "YOUTH"
- series1(2,10) "NOS"
- series2(3,3) "IT"
- series(5,5), "SQA"

so order of labels should be "YOUTH, NOS, IT, SQA"
also, i don't think that the horizontal labels are tied to actual bar locations,
so I would remove the bottom Labels at all, leave only legend